# Use Sha vs md5 or Hash in Snowflake-db

Tags: hash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let me preface by saying that I am not using this for storing passwords or any other sensitive info -- I simply want a row-level sha/hash that I can use later or to quickly check for unique records. My tables will be on the long side, in the range of 0.1 - 10 trillion rows.

I am using a [Snowflake datawarehouse](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-string.html), and thus my options are SHA1, SHA2, MD5 (each with binary options), and [HASH](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/hash.html).

I guess I would like to **minimize the chance of collisions** (given the long tables) while **not burning my compute credits needlessly**.

Which one is the best option given my use case?

Comment: Any "good" hash function (which these all are) uniformly distributes the hashes, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in `hash` function should be good enough if you are ok accepting some conflicts. It can be quite much faster than MD5/SHA functions, and it produces good hashes considering it output, but it produces a smaller range of hashes (64-bit output) and as such is more likely to cause more conflicts.

If you require no conflicts, no hash function will guarantee that, obviously.

`MD5`/`SHA` functions are mostly useful when you want to compute a hash of a string in a form compatible with other systems computing a hash using one of these algorithms.